# What does this command do?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am new at MATLAB, help me understand this

I googled a lot but I couldn't find a correct answer

Any links will also be helpful

1. `[x, fs] = wavread('bee.wav');` This returns the audio files sampling rate in `x`
2. `x = x(1000:1480);`

   What does this do?

   I know `x(:)` makes a column vector, but `x(a:b);` does it make an `m * n` matrix an `n * m`?

Comment: This is *extremely basic* Matlab. You really shouldn't be using StackOverflow as a substitute for spending a bit of time to learn the language. Before you proceed any further, I suggest that you stop, and go through an introductory tutorial or two. The MathWorks lists [numerous tutorials on their site](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html). Your question is covered in chapter one of the [User Guide](http://mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf) and in the [Getting Started video](http://mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-with-matlab-68985.html).

Comment: You can also take a look at the MATLAB tutorial that I provide to first year students.  I was a former part-time instructor and MATLAB is used in my department heavily.  http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~rphan/ppt/ELE532_MATLABTutorial_Full.ppt .  Unfortunately it's an old PPT from way back when... when I didn't understand the best technologies to use for presentations.  I would have done it using LaTeX or `slidify` in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `x = x(1000:1480);` takes a slice out of a given array and puts it back to `x`.

These are basics; you should have a look at a good tutorial.

Examples:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
b = a(2:2:5) % -> [2 4]
c = a(3:end) % -> [3 4 5]
```